# Time limit exceeded in K-th symbol in Grammar (LeetCode)

Tags: python, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

I am taking efforts to solve problem [K-th Symbol in Grammar - LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/k-th-symbol-in-grammar/)

> 779. K-th Symbol in Grammar
>
> On the first row, we write a `0`. Now in every subsequent row, we look at the previous row and replace each occurrence of `0` with `01`, and each occurrence of `1` with `10`.
>
> Given row `N` and index `K`, return the `K`-th indexed symbol in row `N`. (The values of `K` are 1-indexed.) (1 indexed).
>
> ```
> Examples:
> Input: N = 1, K = 1
> Output: 0
>
> Input: N = 2, K = 1
> Output: 0
>
> Input: N = 2, K = 2
> Output: 1
>
> Input: N = 4, K = 5
> Output: 1
>
> Explanation:
> row 1: 0
> row 2: 01
> row 3: 0110
> row 4: 01101001
> ```
>
> **Note:**
>
> 1. `N` will be an integer in the range `[1, 30]`.
> 2. `K` will be an integer in the range `[1, 2^(N-1)]`.

My solution

```
class Solution:
    def kthGrammar(self, N: int, K: int) -> int:
        #replace function
        def replace(row: "List[int]") -> "List[int]":
            """
            rtype: row 
            """
            for i in range(len(row)):
                print(row[i])
                if row[i] == 0: #0 -> 01
                    row.insert(2*i+1, 1)
                elif row[i] == 1: #1 -> 10
                    row.insert(2*i+1, 0)
            return row 

        #helper function 
        def helper(N: int) -> "List(int)":
            """
            rtype:the last row 
            """
            #error case 
            if N < 1: return []
            #base case
            if N == 1:
                res = [0]
                return res 
            elif N > 1:
                return replace(helper(N-1))

        #error cases
        if N < 1 or K < 1 or K > 2**(N-1) : return None 
        #recur        
        row = helper(N)
        #logging.debug(f"row: {row}")
        return row[K-1]
```

Unfortunately it  reported Time Limit Exceeded

> Last executed input:
>   30
>   434991989

Review my solution:

1. employed tail recursion `return replace(helper(N-1))`
2. did not create a new row

It's a relatively fine solution,

What might be the reason of TLE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes little difference how the row is constructed, the problem is intentionally designed such that constructing the row at all will lead to TLE. Consider that for N=30, the row would have 2<sup>29</sup> elements, that's no good. This is usually the case with competitive programming problems, they are made to make the straightforward solutions fail, that is what makes it competitive.

There are a few ways you could go about solving it, for example, you could recognize that the sequence produced is the [Thue-Morse sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence), which has a simple formula to calculate an element at a given index without generating the whole sequence up to that index. The result does not depend on N.